# Laptop freezing when running out of battery on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: power-management, battery, hibernate

When running out of battery and trying to bring the system back up again, I'm faced with a black screen and fans on full.

I've configured hibernate using [guide](https://outhereinthefield.wordpress.com/2019/05/21/enabling-hibernate-on-ubuntu-19-04-disco-dingo/) which sets the swap uuid in the grub file.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=14cee2ec-9d37-4ac0-b594-eae0e55814aa"
```

and sets the swap uuid again in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume`

My swap drive is the same size as my RAM.

However, something is still causing crashes during hibernate only when running out of battery - otherwise hibernate works fine.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq shows you need radically larger swap for Hibernation than if you do not add Hibernation after installation. What's your swap space?

Comment: exact same as my RAM size

Comment: 1) Please see Example Scenarios listed in the above web link and expand the swap space accordingly. Also, 2) which Linux distro have you installed (Ubuntu server, Ubuntu desktop, Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Ubuntu MATE, Mint, et al.), & 3) which release number?  Different releases have different tools for us to recommend. Please click [edit] & add that to your question, so all facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our one-way channel to you. All facts about your PC should go in the Question with [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `/etc/UPower/UPower.conf`

Edit the line

```
CriticalPowerAction=HybridSleep
```

to

```
CriticalPowerAction=Hibernate
```